# What does all this mean? He wondered

Tags: riddle, knowledge

When he woke up, he found himself in a beautiful but strange place. He could hear the sound of ocean waves and feel the warm breeze. “Where am I?” he wondered.

He started walking towards the nearest street intersection. There it was! A board with a map. He looked at it and was more confused than before. What are those lines and spaces? And how can I be in three different places? Is this a map or something else?

[image]

He walked to the intersection and saw three streets coming together.

> First one was named: 4891
>
> Second one: 2014102
>
> Third one: 915758
>
> Right in the cross section of the three streets was a long beautiful
>   area. A big sign in the middle.
>
> **427898   421127   421168**

Now he was really confused. Three different numbers for the same area? And what do these roads lead to?

Where am I?

*This puzzle is my 'Tip of the Hat' to the great puzzle solvers at SE, especially @Tom.*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The diagram seems "obviously" to be

> a periodic table.

If we

> read the numbers as glommed-together strings of atomic numbers, we get 4891 = 4,89,1 = BeAcH = BEACH, 2014102 = 20,14,102 = CaSiNo = CASINO, 915758 = 91,57,58 = PaLaCe = PALACE; 427898 = 42,7,89,8 = MoNAcO = MONACO, 421127 = 42,11,27 = MoNaCo = MONACO (again), and 421168 = 42,11,6,8 = MoNaCO = MONACO (again). The arrows on the diagram correspond to the second of these three.

So you are in

> Monaco

and I think the roads lead to

> some of the places you might want to visit there.

Comment: +H, 53 904919 317590 = 32389216 :)

Comment: That seems a little extreme, but thank you! (Assuming 38 is meant to be 28.)

Comment: (You're welcome. Not too extreme - and yes, my typo!)